# New to SQL-Server, How do i fix msg 8169 error?

Tags: sql-server

```
    INSERT INTO Cars (ID, FirstName, LastName, Manufacturer, Model, Year, Color, 
                      EngineSize, TransmissionType, Sold, Value)
    VALUES ('NEWID()', 'Tony', 'Shannon', 'Volkswagen', 'Polo', '2018', 'Orange',
            '1.0', 'Manual', 'false', '16000');
```

I am brand new to SQL Server and was wondering why i keep getting this error?

*"Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."*

I have set the ID column as a uniqueidentifier but i'm not sure how to generate this?

Please be mindful that i am brand new so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome Niall, Can you please provide your table creation script, or sample data for the table. also are you getting this error when running the insert query or when you are running another query?

Comment: Remove the single quotes, i.e. `NEWID()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Remove the single quotes, i.e. NEWID(). – Felix Pamittan
```

Thank you! This solved my problem!